# Maven exclude wildcard for artifactId

Tags: java, maven

I have list of dependencies, in that I need very few and rest I want to exclude using maven.

Maven dependency tree shows something like this.

```
+- com.test.rtc.utils:com.test.rtc.utils.pamaintenance:jar:2016.2.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  \- com.test.ibm:rtcplain:jar:6.0.2:compile
|     +- com.test.libs:apache-mime4j:jar:0.6:compile
|     +- com.test.libs:com.ibm.icu:jar:4.2.1.v20100412:compile
|     +- com.test.libs:com.ibm.rational.wvcm.ct:jar:3.0.1000.v20151207_2315:compile
|     +- com.test.libs:com.ibm.rational.wvcm.factory:jar:3.0.200.v20151207_2315:compile
|     +- com.test.libs:com.ibm.rational.wvcm.interop:jar:3.1.800.v20151207_2315:compile
|     +- com.test.libs:com.ibm.rational.wvcm.ri.repo:jar:3.0.700.v20151207_2315:compile
|     +- com.test.libs:com.ibm.team.build.client:jar:3.0.1300.v20151207_2315:compile
|     +- com.test.libs:com.ibm.team.build.common:jar:3.1.1300.v20160301_1740:compile
|     +- com.test.libs:com.ibm.team.calm.foundation.common:jar:3.1.1200.v20160205_0047:compile
|     +- com.test.libs:com.ibm.team.connector.scm.client:jar:3.0.1100.v20151207_2315:compile
|     +- com.test.libs:com.ibm.team.connector.scm.common:jar:3.1.200.v20151207_2229:compile
|     +- com.test.libs:com.ibm.team.connector.scm.operations:jar:3.1.500.v20151207_2315:compile
|     +- com.test.libs:com.ibm.team.datawarehouse.common:jar:2.2.1000.v20150218_1646:compile
|     +- com.test.libs:com.ibm.team.dev.jdojo.runtime.common:jar:3.0.800.v20151207_2229:compile
|     +- com.test.libs:com.ibm.team.enterprise.buildablesubset.client:jar:3.1.700.v20160212_0131:compile
|     +- com.test.libs:com.ibm.team.enterprise.buildablesubset.common:jar:3.1.900.v20160211_0055:compile
+- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
..................
..................
```

Here I want to `exclude` only the artifacts in groupId `<groupId>com.test.libs</groupId>` that starts with `com.ibm.team` like this: `<artifactId>com.ibm.team.*</artifactId>`

My maven dependency looks like below:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test.rtc.utils</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.test.rtc.utils.pamaintenance</artifactId>
            <version>${version}</version>
            <exclusions>    
              <exclusion>
              <groupId>com.test.libs</groupId>
              <artifactId>com.ibm.team.*</artifactId>
              </exclusion> 
            </exclusions>
       </dependency>
```

But this is not working. 
How can this be achieved please help.

Comment: Which maven Version do you use?

Comment: It is Maven 3.2.3.

Comment: are you sure your artifact id is com.ibm.team.*, seems you might have miss referenced group for it

Comment: @kuhajeyan, yes artifactId is com.ibm.team.* .

Comment: Example: com.test.libs:com.ibm.team.build.common:jar:3.1.1300.v20160301_1740:compile 
com.test.libs:com.ibm.team.calm.foundation.common:jar:3.1.1200.v20160205_0047:compile. In this "com.ibm.team.build.common" and "com.ibm.team.calm.foundation.common" are artifactId's of of common  groupId "com.test.libs".